# Check if selected date has been change WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, calendar

I want to save the data in my textbox to a file. But my textbox should be clear after the user change the date and the data should be saved. Is there a way to check if the date has been change - something like a bool would be fine.

```
private void calendar_SelectedDatesChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        // ... Get reference.
        var calendar = sender as Calendar;

        // ... See if a date is selected.
        if (calendar.SelectedDate.HasValue)
        {

            DateTime date = calendar.SelectedDate.Value;
            Stream stream = File.Open(date.ToString("MMddyyyy") + ".txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate); // Convert the date to a legal title for a text file
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream);
            if(stream.Length != 0) // Check if stream is not empty 
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
                textbox.Text = sr.ReadToEnd(); 
            }

            //sw.Write(textbox.Text);
            //sw.Dispose(); 

            // ... Display SelectedDate in Title 
            this.Title = date.ToShortDateString();
            stream.Close();
        }

        //textbox.Text = ""; 
    }
```

XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="Terminkalender.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Kalender" Height="350" Width="525" >
<Grid>
    <Calendar   SelectedDatesChanged="calendar_SelectedDatesChanged" Name="calendar" Background="Orange" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="310" Width="178" RenderTransformOrigin="0.528,0.769"/>
    <TextBox Name="textbox" AcceptsReturn="True"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="149" Background="Aqua" Margin="245,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="248"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: where do you set the initial value of the calender ?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare and data bind a `Nullable<DateTime>` property to the `Calendar.SelectedDate` property and add a conditional check to determine whether the value has changed or not:

```
private Nullable<DateTime> selectedDate;
public Nullable<DateTime> SelectedDate
{
    get { return selectedDate; }
    set 
    {
        if (selectedDate != value) { /* SelectedDate has changed */ }
        selectedDate = value; 
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedDate");
    }
}
```

...

```
<Calendar SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDate}" />
```